# Link SQL Server 2016 to a SQL Server 2000 instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2016

I have set up a link to a SQL Server 2000 instance from a SQL Server 2016, details as follows:

- I have used a SQLNCLI10 connection

Here is the relevant code for that, that I have used:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'SQL2000', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI10', @provstr=N'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SQL2000;'
/* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'SQL2000',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
```

- Both servers are set to mixed mode
- I have SA access on both servers
- I do not want to use a local sql login, I am using a domain login
- The error I am getting is:

  > Login failed for user '(null)'. Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.
  >   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "pebbles" returned message "Invalid connection string attribute".
- I have set up this exact same link from another SQL Server 2016 machine to the same SQL Server 2000, and that is completely successful
- The only difference between the SQL Server 2016 than CANNOT connect, and the one that CAN is that the one that CANNOT is SP2 and the one that CAN is SP1
- The SQL Server 2016 machines are both running NT6.3 64 bit
- The SQL Server 2000 machine is on NT5.2 32 bit
- All of the servers are on the same domain

Does anyone have any ideas as to why it is that I cannot successfully link from one SQL Server 2016 to a SQL Server 2000 but I can successfully link from another SQL Server 2016 instance to the exact same SQL Server 2000?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution with `Openquery` since SQL Server 2000 is out of support.

Create

```
 EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'SQLNCLI10', N'AllowInProcess', 1
 GO
 EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'SQL2000', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI10', @datasrc=N'MySql2000Server'
 GO
 EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'SQL2000', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
 GO
 EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'SQL2000', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
 GO
 EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'SQL2000', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
 GO
 EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'SQL2000', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
 GO
 EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'SQL2000', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
 GO
 EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'SQL2000', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
 GO
 EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'SQL2000', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
 GO
 EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'SQL2000', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
 GO
 EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'SQL2000', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
 GO
 EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'SQL2000', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
 GO
 EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'SQL2000', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
 GO
 EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'SQL2000', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
 GO
 EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'SQL2000', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
 GO
 EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'SQL2000', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False', @rmtuser = N'dw', @rmtpassword = N'P@ssword'
 GO
```

Use

```
 select * from openquery (sql2000, 'select @@servername a' )
```

link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2015/05/15/how-to-create-a-linked-server-to-sql-2000-from-sql-2012-or-later/